# How to Refresh a particular part of my web page?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am having an Auto refresh Button, when the button is ON a particular part of my web page should get refresh. For example if I've a DIV, when the button is ON the content in this DIV should reload. If the button is OFF, the DIV should remain the same.

I have the coding only when the Auto Refresh Button is ON the whole page is refreshing. Is that possible to refresh a particular part of a Web Page?

Here is my Coding:-

```
var int=self.setInterval(function(){refreshPage()},60000);
$(document).ready(function() {
   var hashTag = window.location.href.split('#');
   if (hashTag[1] == 'reload') {
      $('#refresh').addClass('refresh-on').html('');  
   }
   $('#refresh').on('click', function() { 
      $(this).toggleClass('refresh-on'); 
      if ($(this).hasClass('refresh-on'))
         $(this).html('Refresh On');
      else 
         $(this).html('Refresh Off');
   });
});

function refreshPage() {
   if ($('#refresh').hasClass('refresh-on')) {
      location.hash = 'reload';
      window.location.reload();
   } else
     location.hash = '';
}
```

Comment: Except for iframes and images, how can the browser reload just part of a web page? If you have a way to do it in your application, you need to define it specifically using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple jquery's load() method if you can save the content to be refreshed in a separate page.

put the content to be refreshed in 'content.php'

```
$("#refreshDIV").load("content.php");
```

you can call this method whenever required and it can load dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the jquery's load() method is a good way to update separated content with external scripts...
Below an example with a little html page which contains 2 divs.
One is refreshing every 1 second and another every 3 seconds...
Divs are using the refreshDiv function to refresh. 
The refreshDiv function takes 3 arguments:

- **div_id**: This is the id of the div you want to refresh;
- **script_file**: The script you want to launch to refresh your div; (scripts/ directory);
- **data**: Some data passed to the script (PHP) by GET method;

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
     <title>Stack OverFlow - 14302842</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function refreshDiv(div_id, script_file, data) {
           var today = new Date();
           $("#"+div_id).load("scripts/"+script_file+"?_"+Math.random()+"&data="+data);           
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            refreshDiv('div1','ls.php','/tmp');
            refreshDiv('div2','ls.php','/home');

            setInterval(function() {
                // Do something every 3 seconds
                refreshDiv('div1','ls.php','/tmp');
            }, 3000);

            setInterval(function() {
               // Do something every 1 seconds
               refreshDiv('div2','ls.php','/home');
            }, 1000);

        });
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="div1" style="color: #F00; border: 1px solid #F00; text-align: center;">Some Text</div>
      <div id="div2" style="color: #00F; border: 1px solid #00F; text-align: center;">Some Text</div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```